# How can I get the sum of a row using LIMIT

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

| id | reg_No | Subj_id | sub_title | score | Class_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 98 | 23 | MATHEMATICS | 90 | 2 |
| 2 | 98 | 21 | ENGLISH LANG | 60 | 2 |
| 3 | 98 | 24 | PHYSICS | 78 | 2 |
| 4 | 98 | 23 | CHEMISTRY | 100 | 2 |
| 5 | 98 | 21 | BIOLOGY | 81 | 2 |
| 6 | 98 | 24 | AGRICULTURE | 87 | 2 |

I want to select the best `SUM(score)` of the four(4) subjects including English and mathematics.

It suppose to sum 90+60+100+87 = 337

But, it's summing the entire column

Here is my query

```sql
SELECT SUM(score) 
FROM table1 
WHERE reg_no = 98 
  AND class_id=2 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN sub_title IN ('English Language','Mathematics') 
              THEN 0 
              ELSE 1 END, score DESC LIMIT 4
```

Comment: Select with ORDER BY and LIMIT in subquery then SUM().

Comment: Which database are you using SQL Server or MySQL, also you don't need the phpmyadmin or php tags if you just want a SQL statement.

Comment: I don't get it there are only 2 scores for 'English Language','Mathematics' (90,60) in your sample so where do  scores of 100+87 come from?

Comment: @P.Salmon OP wants scores of English and Mats, plus two highest other scores.

Comment: @michel, perhaps , I wonder if resits are possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to split into two queries. The first one gets the Math and English score values, and the second one gets the two highest scores from the remaining values.

SQL Server:

```
With CTE As (
Select Top 2 Score From table1 Where reg_no = 98 And class_id=2 And sub_title Not In ('MATHEMATICS','ENGLISH LANG') 
Order by Score Desc
Union All
Select Score From table1 Where reg_no = 98 And class_id=2 And sub_title In ('MATHEMATICS','ENGLISH LANG')
)
Select Sum(Score)
From CTE
```

MySQL:

```
With CTE As (
Select Score
From
(Select Score From table1 Where reg_no = 98 And class_id=2 And sub_title Not In ('MATHEMATICS','ENGLISH LANG')
 Order by Score Desc
 Limit 2) As S
Union All
Select Score From table1 Where reg_no = 98 And class_id=2 And sub_title In ('MATHEMATICS','ENGLISH LANG')
)
Select Sum(Score)
From CTE
```

Comment: There is no TOP in mysql , mysql equivalent is LIMIT..

Comment: @P.Salmon There is also an sql-server tag.

Comment: My comment is still valid - if you are providing a sql server only answer then you could help the OP out by saying so.

Answer (score 2):

The priority of `SELECT` is higher than `LIMIT`, therefore, you have to use a subquery

```
SELECT sum(score) 
FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM tab
    WHERE reg_no = 98 AND class_id=2
    ORDER BY CASE WHEN sub_title IN ('English Language','Mathematics') 
                  THEN 0 
                  ELSE 1 END, score DESC 
    LIMIT 4 
) t
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=82095c3e27a701ed34cfe3989f32da95)

Comment: *The priority of SELECT is higher than LIMIT* ??? What do you mean?

Comment: @Akina https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.15/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/select-statement/select-lexical-vs-logical-order/

Comment: I cannot find the word "priority" by your link. And I don't see a relation between what is written there and what is actually happening. As well as I don 't see the relation between JOOQ and MySQL / SQL Server. PS. Where are lateral joins, window functions, etc. in the scheme by your link?

Comment: @Akina logical order = priority

Comment: There is a phrase which is shamefacedly skipped: "In fact, everything is not like that - but if you think that everything is exactly like that, there will be no big trouble."

Comment: @Akina you are right jooq is not MySQL. I was lazy to search for MySQL-specific text. However, it doesn't matter. The SQL SELECT clause priority is part of all relational DBMS in similar way.